# jquery getJSON method wait forever if the request takes a long time

Tags: jquery, getjson

This is my jsp file

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Heelo;
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    console.log('something');
    $.getJSON('test', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my servlet file

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(360000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    PrintWriter out = null;
    try {
        out = response.getWriter();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    out.write("[]");
}
```

This is a request sent to a servlet. But if this servlet takes a long time (for example, 6 minutes) to process, there is no data printed to console. In the example above, I can see 'something' printed to console, but no '[]'.

But if I do a `curl` to that servlet directly, I can get the result back.

Any help?

Comment: Why would you expect the client to wait 6 minutes for a result?

Comment: @MikeBrant Because my servlet has a query to database which may take a very long time, so here I just force it to wait for 6 minutes to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since getJSON runs on the client and curl on the server, this could be network related issue. 
Could you use fiddler/chrome webdeveloper tools to see what is taking time.
It could be simple things like name resolution, or webserver configurations.

Comment: I just created a very simple test which doesn't work and i updated the question.

Comment: Any configuration settings for Tomcat? Cause this works for me when I run it locally, but not on the server.

Answer (score 0):

It could be time out.
See the how to handle time out in the following dicussion.

[jQuery getJSON with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138470/jquery-getjson-with-timeout)

> ```
> $.ajax({
>   url: url,
>   dataType: 'json',
>   data: data,
>   success: callback,
>   timeout: 360000
> });
> ```

Comment: No, its not, i tried to set timeout to be a big number, but it doesn't work.