# How to set JSON API timeout for a website?

Tags: javascript, json

I searched already the stackoverflow website for this solution, but i can't find any solution that fit with my problem.

I'm requesting a API .. but when that api website is offline it need to be abort/timeout that requests.

Any idea how to do that?

Here is my script:

```js
function getStreamDetails() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $.getJSON('https://mywebsite.com/streaminfo.php', function(data) {
        var artist = data['song'];
        var title = data['song'];
        var artistClean = artist.length > 50 ? artist.substring(0, 50) + "..." : artist;

        var music = artistClean;
        var formattedMusic = music.replace(/;/g, ', ');
        var dj = data['live'] == '' ? 'Auto DJ' : data['live'];

        $('#dj').html(dj);
        $('#listeners').html(data['Plays']);
        $('#song').html(formattedMusic);
        $('#song').attr('data-original-title', formattedMusic);
    });
}

setInterval(getStreamDetails, 60000);
getStreamDetails();
```

Hope someone can help me out :))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138470/jquery-getjson-with-timeout

Comment: 1. Don't use `setInterval()`, use `setTimeout()` instead. To detect a timeout, use the `fail()` promise.

Comment: @MrD I already tried that, but doens't fit with my code.

Comment: @benM What if the url is offline then setTimeout have no effect.. I want to check the url like every X for online, if not then it need to connection timeout the request.

Comment: You should call `setTimeout` again once you have a response from the API (regardless of its status).

Comment: Can you post a snippet about this here? @benm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery getJSON with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138470/jquery-getjson-with-timeout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look @ the following article: https://it.toolbox.com/blogs/edmonbegoli/adjusting-jquery-json-timeouts-101508

I will quote from [there](https://it.toolbox.com/blogs/edmonbegoli/adjusting-jquery-json-timeouts-101508):

> If you are making JSON AJAX calls with jQuery and if you are
>   experiencing errors changing timeout value[...] AJAX call may help
>   alleviate the problem.
>
> If you are working with $.getJSON method, you
>   will notice that there is no option to specify the timeout value.
>   Hence, you have two options: 
>   1. Change the `$.getJSON`, which is just a wrapper method, to `$.ajax`. So, from

```
`$.getJSON("http://someurl", //Gives us parsed JSON automatically 
{ somparam: params }, //The params for the query resultsHandler 
//The callback function that handles JSON results );
```

> change the `$.getJSON` call to `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({url:"http://someurl", dataType:'json', data: "someparam=" +
params,timeout: 7000, success:resultsHandler })
```

> Notice the value for
>   timeout is 7000, or 7 seconds.
>
> For more details please consult [$.ajax documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options).
>
> 2. Another alternative is to set the global AJAX parameters before the call to getJSON and then make all your getJSON
>      and AJAX calls with these settings.

```
$.ajaxSetup({ timeout: 7000 });
$.getJSON("http://someurl", //Gives us parsed JSON automatically {
somparam: params }, //The params for the query resultsHandler //The
callback function that handles JSON results );
```

> For more details see [$.ajaxSetup documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajaxSetup).